# change text input's value without using setState

Tags: react-native

I'am triying to change text input's value without using setState becauce when we use setstate we will render component in each keystroke but I did not find anything

Comment: that's how you update text input value.

Comment: Using controlled components is recommended. By the way you may be interested in reading about uncontrolled ones: [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html). This is the official React doc, but you can extends it to RN.

Comment: but the component will be rendered every time I type or delete a letter for nothing
is it normal?

Comment: This is how React works: component rendering reflects component state. But note that it will re-render just the parts which need to be re-rendered, not the whole component

Comment: If you don't want the component to re-render, how do you expect to see a visible change of the value ?

Comment: thanks very much Jukius L, Milore and Kape.
I have change props value of text Input to default Value. It work
 i.e I can make the change without use state
what is your point of view on this thing?

Comment: @Milore wrong, it does re-render EVERYTHING in the render method

Answer (score 1):

***you can use ref and setNativeProps***

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

export default App = () => {
  clearText = () => {
     _textInput.setNativeProps({text: ''});
  }

    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <TextInput
          ref={component => _textInput = component}
          style={{height: 50, width: 200, marginHorizontal: 20, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#ccc'}}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={clearText}>
          <Text>Clear text</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
}
```

for more info take a look at the following

[React native direct manipulation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ref.setNativeProps({ text: dummyText })` but problem with this approach is that it will not give you `onFocus` callback.